# How to reduce spikes of GC CPU usage

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jvm

I've got a memory-intensive `Java 8` server application, which is also latency-sensitive. The application runs fine with `2.5G` heap but there are *spikes* of `garbage collector` CPU usage once a day,

Now I wonder how to reduce the spikes. I probably can't reduce the memory usage or add more memory. I am Ok with the *average* CPU usage of `GC`.  I would like just to *distribute* the CPU load over time evenly. Is it possible ?

Comment: Which algorithm do you use?

Comment: Have you read through [Oracle's guidelines for tuning the Java garbage collector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/index.html)?

Comment: @JakubKubrynski I have `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`. Is it what you mean ?

Comment: @BobJarvis No, thanks for the reference.

Comment: @Michael you can check -XX:+UseG1GC. And please get more data from GC Logs. Probably those spikes are cause by full gc's.

Comment: @JakubKubrynski They are the spikes of  `ConcurrentMarkSweep`. It takes 30% of CPU for 5-10 min.

Comment: @JakubKubrynski Could you explain please why I should check `-XX:+UseG1GC` ?

Comment: @JakubKubrynski I am going to add GC logs. Suppose I've got them. What should I look for in the logs?

Comment: @Michael usually G1 requires less tuning than CMS. It's worth to check at the beginning

Comment: @Michael import your logs in GC Viewer to see details

Comment: @JakubKubrynski What is the `GC Viewer` ? Thanks for the quick responses by the way.

Comment: @Michael https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer

Comment: @JakubKubrynski Oh, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should make sure that it's the CPU utilization that introduces latency and not stop-the-world pauses (e.g. Full GC if you're using CMS).

If Full GCs are not the issue then you can inspect the effective VM flags of your application by starting it with all present flags (present flags may affect the defaults of others) and then appending `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal`.

Look for `ConcGCThreads` and see if reducing that number has the desired effect. It'll use less cores (but more walltime) for the concurrent cycles.